# React Native: App is getting disconnected right after getting installed into emulator

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

```
react-native run-android
```

after thing command app is getting installed into emulator succesfully but getting disconnected from terminal.

[image]

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "clean": "npm cache verify && cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..",
    "android": "npm run install && npm run start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.53.0",
    "react-native-facebook-login": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.0.6",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-actions": "2.2.1",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "22.1.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

below image of Logcat in Android Studio.

[image]

I dint see anything suspicions. Thanks

**Tried:**

```
mkdir android/app/src/main/assets
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
react-native run-android
```

and

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && react-native run-android
```